# PostgreSQL exception handling on select statements with calculations

Tags: postgresql

I'm having issues with the exception handling of postgresql, and I'm looking for some tips/advice how to tackle this.
Say I want to do the following:

```
SELECT col1 / col2
FROM table
```

The first problem that arises is that if at some point a value in col2 = 0, the query throws an exception. A solution to this is to add a `NULLIF()` in the denominator.

In our case, users can make their own formulas, which have to be parsed by the database, so we do not have the knowledge about the division in advance. We could make a fancy formula parser that adds `NULLIF()` in the right places, but then don't get me started on taking square root of negative numbers..

So I'm wondering if there is a better solution to the problem. Does something like this exist?

```
SELECT col1 / col2
  exception
   return null
FROM table
```

Or do I need to make use of the 'function' feature of postgresql? Is it possible to combine two columns like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefunction(col1, col2) RETURNS real AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN col1 / col2;
    exception when division_by_zero then
        return null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT somefunction(col1, col2, ..)
FROM table;
```

So keep in mind that we do not know the formula in advance!
Thanks!

Comment: If you give your users the permission to directly write SQL expressions, you also give them the responsibility to write proper valid SQL and add the `nullif()` calls themselves. Surely you already set up all the relevant safeguards to limit sql injections? Catching exceptions in there should be easy. If no, then yeah you definitely should use a fancy formula parser!

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks for your answer. We have some safeties in place, but in general it's not the nicest thing to do of course. Could you elaborate on 'Catching exceptions in there should be easy'?

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can define your own operators. Given your function, you could

```
CREATE OPERATOR public./ (
   LEFTARG = real,
   RIGHTARG = real
   FUNCTION = public.somefunction
);

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

This would use your custom function for every division.

Allowing your users to run SQL statements is a bad idea. SQL is so powerful that they can do anything - they can change the `search_path`, and they can easily bring your database server to its knees.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your answer. Completely agree that user generated SQL commands is a bad idea. This is for internal use, so we can get away with shady stuff.